# How create an AjaxToolKit control, (rating), from code-behind in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, code-behind, rating

*I am creating dinamically controls from code-behind*, such as textbox, checkboxlist, radiobuttonlist, etc etc... and adding them in a placeholder inside a repeater, in order to create a dynamic survey from a template-user-made, the questions of the survey I want 'em to be created from code-behind, but if there's any other way for creating dynamically the controls, could you guys guide me with a specific topic or show me a code-example?

I was thinking something like..

```
 AjaxControlToolkit.Rating rateThing = new AjaxControlToolkit.Rating();
                    rateThing.CurrentRating = 3;
                    rateThing.MaxRating = 5;
                    rateThing.StarCssClass = "ratingStar";
                    rateThing.WaitingStarCssClass = "savedRatingStar";
                    rateThing.FilledStarCssClass = "filledRatingStar";
                    rateThing.EmptyStarCssClass = "emptyRatingStar";
                    rateThing.ID = "rateThing" + IdPregunta.Value;
                    rateThing.Visible = true;

                    placeholder.Controls.Add(rateThing);
```

but it doesn't render ...

P.D. I already added the images the example need in the css to create the stars of the control, tried reading about rating in MS with [this rating ajaxtoolkit stuff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/ajax-control-toolkit/rating/creating-a-rating-control-cs) and with other stuff without success :(

**EDITED**: Never got figured it out so I choose for an RadioButtonList for creating the control in codebehind then using CSS and JS/JQuery for creating the real pseudocontrol of rating

> **You could use this as a guide for the codebehind**

```
RadioButtonList rblEscala = new RadioButtonList();
    rblEscala.ID = "rblRes" + IdPregunta.Value;
    rblEscala.CssClass = "input-sm form-control col-sm-12 star-cb-group";
    rblEscala.Style.Add("height", "auto !important;");
    for (int i = 5; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        rblEscala.Items.Add(new ListItem("☆", i.ToString()));
    }
    rblEscala.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;

    placeholder.Controls.Add(rblEscala);
```

In the front use this link as reference: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PKxQYY

Answer (score 0):

> I'll free my code so you can use it, as a base for your custom rating
>   hehehe

For the **CodeBehind** try using a PlaceHolder and using this:

```
                    RadioButtonList rblEscala = new RadioButtonList();
                    rblEscala.ID = "rblRes";
                    rblEscala.CssClass = "star-cb-group";
                    rblEscala.Style.Add("height", "auto !important;");
                    for (int i = 5; i >= 1; i--)
                    {
                        //rblEscala.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
                        rblEscala.Items.Add(new ListItem("☆", i.ToString()));
                    }
                    rblEscala.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;

                    placeholder.Controls.Add(rblEscala);
```

For **CSS** Use this:

```
    .star-cb-group {
        /* remove inline-block whitespace */
        font-size: 0;
        /* flip the order so we can use the + and ~ combinators */
        unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
        direction: rtl;
        /* the hidden clearer */
    }

        .star-cb-group tbody {
            float: left;
        }

        .star-cb-group * {
            font-size: 2.5rem;
        }

        .star-cb-group input {
            display: none;
            background: none;
        }

        .star-cb-group label {
            background: none !important;
            padding-left: 5px !important;
            height: auto !important;
        }

        .star-cb-group input + label {
            color: #888;
        }

        .star-cb-group input:checked + label {
            color: #e52;
        }
```

For **JS/Jquery** I added this:

```
        try {
            $(".star-cb-group input").change(function () {
                //$(this).next().text("★");
                var inputs = $(this).parent().parent().children().children("input");
                var bandera = false;
                inputs.each(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(':checked') || bandera) {
                        $(this).next().text("★");
                        $(this).next().css("color", "#e52");
                        $(this).next().css("font-weight", "Bold !important");
                        bandera = true;
                    } else {
                        $(this).next().text("☆");
                        $(this).next().css("color", "#888");
                        $(this).next().css("font-weight", "normal !important");
                    }
                });
            });
        } catch (err2) {
            console.log(err2);
        }
```